# "Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted)" using arithmetic in TikZ foreach

Tags: tikz-pgf, errors

I am using a `\foreach` loop in TikZ with `\i in {2,3,..,5}` and I'd like to be able to use the value `\i-1`. However, every approach I have tried gives me a `Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted)` error. Below are three minimal examples with my different attempts after reading some answer in this and other forums:

With the `evaluate` option:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (N1) {N1};
\foreach \i [evaluate=\i as \j using \i-1] in {2,3,..,5}{
  % whatever
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

With `\pgfmathtruncatemacro`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (N1) {N1};
\foreach \i in {2,3,..,5}{
  \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\j}{\i - 1}
  % whatever
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

With `\pgfmathparse`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (N1) {N1};
\foreach \i in {2,3,..,5}{
  \pgfmathparse{\i - 1}
  % whatever
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I have seen plenty of similar examples supposed to work, what am I missing?

My version of PGF/TikZ (as reported by `\pgfversion`) is 3.0.0.

PD: I know that `foreach` supports iterating over two variables at the same time, so I could use `\foreach \i / \j in {2/1, 3/2, 4/3, 5/4}`, but that doesn't scale too well.

Comment: You need to use three periods in the `2,3,...,5` expression, not two.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to use three periods in the `2,3,...,5` expression, not two.