# Two problems with foreach - TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

Note: This is a major edit to my original question. I intended to ask another question for the second problem separately, but it has already been initiated in the comment and probably already answered here. So I have edited this question instead to cover all two of them.

**FIRST Problem: Illegal unit of measure: (pt inserted)**

I am facing a similar problem as ["Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted)" using arithmetic in TikZ foreach](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/186916/illegal-unit-of-measure-pt-inserted-using-arithmetic-in-tikz-foreach). Except that I am using negative decimal numbers as well as positive decimal numbers and I have used three dots here for the interval. The MWE is as below:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \x/\y in {-1.4/-1.4,-1.2/-1.2,...,1.6/1.6}{
\filldraw (\x,\y) circle [radius=2pt];}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

How do I fix this? I know there is an alternative way to get the same picture. But I am experimenting with this for some purpose. I have passed here equal values of x and y. The problem is not that if there is an alternative way to make the same picture. The problem is that if there is a way to workaround with this error and get rid of it. This is because I may change the values of y and may still find the same error lurking in.

**SECOND Problem: Using two foreach to make an ordered pair**

The second problem is how I can use two `foreach` commands to make an ordered pair so that one doesn't iterate over the iteration of the other, but forms a one-to-one correspondence or something like that. Some suggests to use `evaluate` in `foreach`. This is okay when I know y depends on x. But how about when y doesn't depend on x at all? When y has some random values for example? The MWE is

```
\documentclass[border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \x  in {1,...,9}
\foreach \y  in {2,5,4,6,9,1,3,8,7}
\filldraw (\x,\y) circle [radius=10pt];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which gives:

[image: Unexpectedresult]

What I want is:

[image: Expected result]

Comment: You cannot use the triple dots syntax for multiple variables I believe (e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37601).

Comment: Oh! that depressed me.

Comment: As mentioned in the answer to that question though, and as SebGlav mentions in his comment, you may be able to use `evaluate`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe something like this as a workaround...

```
\documentclass[border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \x [count=\xcnt] in {-1.4,-1.2,...,1.6}{%
\foreach \y [count=\ycnt] in {-1.4,-1.2,...,1.6}{%
\ifnum\xcnt=\ycnt\filldraw (\x,\y) circle [radius=2pt];\fi
}}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \x [count=\xcnt] in {-1.4,-1.2,...,1.6}{%
\foreach \y [count=\ycnt] in {-2.8,-2.4,...,3.2}{%
\ifnum\xcnt=\ycnt\filldraw (\x,\y) circle [radius=2pt];\fi
}}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I have updated the question. But you already answered what I needed haha. So thanks. It works. Could you explain `count` and ifs`\xcnt` and '\ycnt' named arbitrarily?

Comment: Since I don't understand how this answer properly your question (points are aligned here, and you want `\y` to be *randomly chosen*, I'll give another try. See my new answer.

Comment: Sorry, I misread this answer in the first place, its fine and works properly (the aligned points gave me the impression of the contrary).

Comment: @M.A.Bromuela When one says `\foreach \x [count=\xcnt] in {-1.4,-1.2,...,1.6}`, the first time through the loop, `\x` equals `-1.4`; however, `\xcnt=1`, meaning the first item in the list (etc for subsequent loop circuits).  I use a comparison of the x and y counts (not substitution values), so that I only execute the `\filldraw` when `\xcnt = `\ycnt`.

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you just do this?

```
\documentclass[border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \x in {-1.4,-1.2,...,1.6}{
\filldraw (\x,\x) circle [radius=2pt];}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: That's because I will change the y-values to some other values. to form some ordered-pairs. I am actually trying to make some ordered-pairs using two `foreach` if possible.

Comment: The only problem is if I use two foreach one after the other, the first one iterates over the iteration of the second one.

Comment: So you will have to type them all, unless `\y` can be computed from `\x`. In this case, you can use the following syntax: `\foreach[evaluate=\y using <your formula>] \x in {<your series>}`.

Comment: Please complete your question with an actual list that you want to loop in, so that we can help you out.

Comment: I have updated the question. But before I updated it looks like @Steven B. Segletes already answered what I needed. Thanks for your effort.

Answer (score 2):

Just mentioning this as well. If you have a list of values that you want to place at regular intervals, one loop with a counter is enough:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach [count=\x] \y  in {2,5,4,6,9,1,3,8,7}
   \filldraw (\x,\y) circle [radius=10pt];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

If the values should start at some specific value, you can say e.g. `count=\x from 10`, and if the `\x` should have a different spacing, you can probably use `evaluate`, e.g. `\foreach [count=\x, evaluate={\NewX=2*\x + 4;}]` which will make `\NewX` 6, 8, 10, ...

```
\documentclass[border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach [count=\x, evaluate={\NewX=2*\x+4;}] \y  in {2,5,4,6,9,1,3,8,7}
   \filldraw (\NewX,\y) circle [radius=10pt];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Now that you edited your question, it seems that you want to draw points at every `\x` integer coordinates but with *randomly chosen* `\y` coordinates.

In my opinion, this is what `[count=\x from 1]` is made for:

[image: random y coordinates]

```
\documentclass[border=3.14mm,tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \foreach \y [count=\x from 1] in {2,5,4,6,9,1,3,8,7}
            \filldraw (\x,\y) circle [radius=10pt];
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the second problem, this works:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \coords in {(1,2),(2,5),(3,4),(4,6),(5,9),(6,1),(7,3),(8,8),(9,7)}
\filldraw \coords circle [radius=10pt];
\end{tikzpicture}
```

See the section "Special handling of pairs" on page 1002 of [the PGF manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf), under section 88 "Repeating Things: The Foreach Statement".